# The way how to control access authority to metadata of token?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to make following function with customized tokens. The goal is to mint tokens including metadata which is only exposed to the owner of token. This means that no one is permitted to read the metadata other than the owner. Is it possible to create such tokens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that with [Attribute Based Access Control](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control) with the help of Hyperledger Fabric CA,  [Chaincode's client identity library](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/lib/cid/README.md) and some programming related key management techniques.

In Chaincode Side:

To store metadata, the chaincode will get the owner/user certificate with the help of client identity library and by parsing that certificate, chaincode will get certificate user's/owner's public key and hold the  public key with a variable named as "variablePublicKey" and after that will store it's metadata with key "variablePublicKey.metadata".

To read the metadata, the chaincode will get the owner/user certificate with the help of client identity library and by parsing that certificate, chaincode will get certificate user's/owner's public key and hold the  public key with a variable named as "variablePublicKey" and after that will get it's metadata with key "variablePublicKey.metadata".

To ensure security with this system, your chaincode must need to add some substring with each of user Input key. For example if user want to invoke or to query a car type asset, the chaincode will always add a substring with that user input, like user input key is "xyz" so the chaincode will add a substring with that like "xyz.car" and store/update value against the "xyz.car" key. To query a car, if the user give the input as "xyz", the chaincode will add a substring with that like "xyz.car" and query value against the "xyz.car" key